# ruby on rails nil.to_sym error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not even sure how this broke. And I don't really know what the error means either. It was working previously.

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.to_sym
  Extracted source (around line #3):

    1: <div id="probes">
    2:  <h1>Edit Probes</h1>
    3:  <% form_for @probe do |f| %>
    4:      <%= f.error_messages %>
    5:    <p>
    6:      <%= f.label "Site name" %><br />
```

The controller:

```
def edit
  @probe = Probe.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is also happening on the index action

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.to_sym

10:   <% for probe in @probes %>
11:     <tr>
12:       <td class="detail" style="padding-left: 100px;" width="50%">
13:         <%=h link_to probe.name, probe %>
14:     </td>
15:       <td class="detail" style="padding-left: 30px;" width="30%">
16:         <%=h @status[x] %>
```

The controller:

```
@probes = @current_user.probes.find_existing_probes_for_user
@status_dump = []
for probe in @probes
    @status_dump << probe.status
end
@status = []
for id in @status_dump
    case id
        when 0 then @status << ....
        when 1 then @status << ....
        when 2 then @status << ....
        when 3 then @status << ....
    end
end
```

The find is coming back with data, I'm using ruby debugger.

**EDIT**

For the index action, it has to do with the probe in the link to.

**EDIT 2**
I changed probe to edit_probe_path(probe.id) and that works. I'm still not sure why the edit page is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had to do with how my links were setup. After messing with them, it seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It means your find was unsuccessful and you need to do more error handling.

Comment: And @probe is getting assigned the information that comes back from the database.